# How to add multiple fields in a document in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save the Device Tokens of some device in a SINGLE DOCUMENT, in DIFFERENT FIELDS.

Here is my code,

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshots) {
                if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
                    snapshots.hasData) {
                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshots.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshots.data[index];
                        Map location = doc.data;
                        String fieldname = 'f$index';

                        var dtoken = location['deviceToken'];

                       
                         

                          _firestore.collection('deviceTokens').add({
                            fieldname: dtoken,
                          });
                       
                     
              

                       
                        return Text(
                          "xyz",
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
```

I want to store multiple deviceTokens in a single document.

To be more clear,

When this code runs, i want ONLY A SINGLE DOCUMENt created in my database, which is having device tokens in multiple fields like,

in a single document-

f1:"1st device token",

f2:"2nd device token",

fn:"nth device token"

But this code creates many documents having different device tokens(1 field per document).

Please help

UPDATED CODE

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshots) {
                if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
                    snapshots.hasData) {
                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshots.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        var docid;

                        if (index == 0) {
                         _firestore
                              .collection('devicetokens')
                              .add({}).then((value) => docid = value);
                        }
                        DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshots.data[index];
                        Map location = doc.data;
                        String fieldname = 'f$index';


                        var dtoken = location['deviceToken'];

                        DocumentReference docss =
                            _firestore.collection("devicetokens").document(docid);
                        docss.setData({
                          fieldname: dtoken,
                        });
                        
                       

                       
                        return Text(
                          "xyz",
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
```

Comment: You should get a document first, then write to it

Comment: How can i do that, could you please explain, it'll be really helpful

Comment: If my answer is useful please accept it, otherwise let me know

Comment: Is there any reason why you need each token to be in a different field? That seems unnecessarily complex.  You could instead just push the token into a single array field.

Comment: @DougStevenson All i want is to trigger my cloud function to send notification to those device tokens whom i have in the fields of that newly created document(i'll delete the doc after sending the notification). Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: umm..and there is one more thing , at first, the device tokens are in another collection, based on certain conditions, i retrieve some device tokens and save them in different fields of a document in another collection so that i can send them notification using my cloud function

Comment: @DougStevenson dude i understood what you said. thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
_firestore.collection('deviceTokens').add({
  fieldname: dtoken,
});
```

With something like this:

```
  DocumentReference doc = _firestore.collection(deviceTokens).document();
  doc.setData({
    "f1" : "1st device token",
    "f2" : "2nd device token",
    "fn" :"nth device token",
  });
```

---

**EDIT**: Here's one way you can do it. Get the docid synchronously using `.document()` method.
Don't use `.collection.add()` to get a docID as it's asychronous, meaning it will be null until the future resolve (until the server returns with the docID). You need to already have the docID to write to it with `setData`.

This should work. Or at least put you well on your path to the solution.

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshots) {
                if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
                    snapshots.hasData) {

                    //This gets you a doc ID synchronously
                    DocumentReference docid = _firestore.collection(deviceTokens).document();

                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshots.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        

                        DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshots.data[index];
                        Map location = doc.data;
                        String fieldname = 'f$index';


                        var dtoken = location['deviceToken'];    

                        _firestore.collection("devicetokens")
                        .document(docid.documentID)
                        .setData({
                          fieldname: dtoken,
                        });
                        
                       

                       
                        return Text(
                          "xyz",
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
```

Comment: it creates 3 documents

Comment: i want the "f1",f2" to be dynamic, so that for "n" numbers of device tokens, it can create "n" fields in the same document

Comment: you can make them dynamic. Just replace them with a variable name. They just have to be strings.

Comment: It does not create 3 documents.  `doc.setData will write to one document each time its called.

Comment: There is probably an error somewhere else in your code. Whats is the documents? Do the documents have all the same data them?

Comment: I think youre on the right track with your updated example. Except for the `if (index==0){...}` The firestore call inside is a future so it wont work. You'll need to get your docid synchronously or otherwise, you'll have to use a futureBuilder

Comment: I've updated my answer to get the docID synchronously. If this solution helps you please accept my answer

Comment: It didn't work, again, new documents were created with different ids and fields :(

Comment: Hey! thanks, this also worked for me, i did some changes :)